# How to create REST APIs for a MATLAB code and host it other than using MATLAB Production Server?

Tags: reactjs, matlab, rest

As the title, how can I create REST APIs for my MATLAB code as I created an ANN model and would like to call it from a React App. Is there any way other than hosting it on MATLAB Production Server where it automatically creates the APIs for me. I also believe it requires additional license.

I expect my React app is able to call an API and pass in some parameters for the ANN model to process which returns me the final results. Basically the ANN model acts like an "external function" I can call and use.